# Copying Visual Studio Team System 2010 queries

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I am using VS Team System 2010.  I have several TFS queries.  Like with most queries, if I have one that works, I often want to create variants of that query.   However, I can find no ability to copy a query.  I either need to overwrite an existing query or start from scratch.  Also, if I have a query and alter it, there is no "Save As" option so that I can save the altered query under a different name (usually to preserve a widely used query).

So, is there a way to do this?  Is there a means via the Team System Power Tools perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

You can duplicate an existing query by copying and pasting (right-click on the existing query, select "Copy" and then right-click on your query folder and select "Paste".)  It will prompt you to use a new name if you're pasting to the same folder as the existing query.

Answer (score 1):

"File->Save As" works for queries.

Comment: It does - the only caveat is that you need to be in Edit Query mode instead of Run Query mode.